# How to use this contract in nodejs? Thanks

Tags: contract-invocation, tutorials

I got this contract that seems to meet what I need, but I don't know how to make the calls from nodejs, could you help me? Thank you

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Rewards is Ownable {
    IERC20 public rewardsToken;

    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;

    constructor(address _rewardsToken) {
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardsToken);
    }

    function setReward(address account,uint256 amount)  public onlyOwner  {
        rewards[account] = amount;
    }

    function claimReward() public{
        uint256 reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
        rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward*10**18);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use libraries such as [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/getting-started.html) or [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/) to interact with them.

As linked both of these provide some nice steps how to get started, but you can also find a lot of tutorials on the web:

- https://trufflesuite.com/tutorial/
- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/

Edit:

Example with `ethers`:

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";

// See https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/
const jsonRpc = "some json rpc (e.g. infura)"
const provider = new new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(jsonRpc)
// See https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet
const privateKey = "some private key"
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider)

// Manually define abi for the simplicity of the exmaple
// Solidity also creates a abi definition when compiling the contract that can be used.
const rewardsAbi = [
  "function setReward(address account,uint256 amount) public",
  "function claimReward() public",
]

const rewardsAddress = "0x<some_address>"
// Use signer here as we want to change the state
// See https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--writing
const rewardsContract = new ethers.Contract(rewardsAddress, rewardsAbi, wallet);

const tx = await rewardsContract.claimReward()
// Wait for the tx to be mined
const receipt = await tx.wait()
```

Comment: could you give me a little example with the ClaimReward function? Could you help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a simple example that uses `ethers` to the answer. but you can do the same with web3js

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot